# How to show Oracle index was used in sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question on Oracle Index.
create an index for department_name attribute of departments table.
Prove that the index will be used in the SQL statement below.
select * from departments where department_name='COMPUTER'

i created index but i was not sure how to prove it, because index can't be seen in the SQL statement.

Create index dept.idx on departments(department_name);

select * from departments where department_name='COMPUTER'

How to prove ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Explain Plan, it will tell you what the DB is planning on using to run the query,

```
--Generate explain plan.
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select * from departments where department_name='COMPUTER';

--Display explain plan.
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Comment: Thanks @jonearles I was just getting back to add in the Display part!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER INDEX dept.idx MONITORING USAGE;

select * from departments where department_name='COMPUTER'

SELECT index_name,
   table_name,
   monitoring,
   used,
   start_monitoring,
   end_monitoring
FROM   v$object_usage
WHERE  index_name = 'IDX'
ORDER BY index_name;
```